# Why is it difficult for $GCT$ to prove super quadratic lower bound?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds

We have a quadratic lower bound for the Permanent versus Determinant problem.

Why is it difficult for $GCT$ to improve it?

Comment: Do you mind telling us what GCT means?

Comment: I guess https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_complexity_theory